# next.js 13 loading component add transition

Tags: animation, next.js, css-transitions, loading, next.js13

I'm trying to add a transition animation to the loading component that comes with next.js 13. but as soon as I click on the link, the inside of the page is emptied and the back part remains blank.

you can review this code for better understanding:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/musing-tdd-c56h1h

so what I want to do is that the page does not disappear during the transition. maybe there is a way to do this with framer-motion. I couldn't find it on the internet, I would be glad if you help me